# check class magnific popup trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to check class magnific popup trigger before popup open but alert show "undefined". How to get it "add_group" or "edit_group".

this is my code

```
$('.add_group,.edit_group').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      focus:'#group_komponen',
      modal:true,
      callbacks: {
         beforeOpen: function() {
              alert($(this).attr('class'));
         }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For solution to check "Class" before PopUp open. You need to check the length of that "Class" like below code:

```
if(($('.add_group').length) || ($('.edit_group').length) ) {

   $('.add_group,.edit_group').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      focus:'#group_komponen',
      modal:true,
      callbacks: {
         beforeOpen: function() {
              alert($(this).attr('class'));
         }
     }
   });

}
```